# Update value of custom data attribute in context menu

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, contextmenu

I have a list of phone numbers and multiple functions operating on them.

1. Edit the phone number.
2. Remove the phone number.

So I have used a context menu and set it for list because I have multiple `phonenumbers` and have to dynamically set the attribute for each of them.

I have a format `phonenumber` function in the helper which displays the phone number and the code for that goes as follows :-

```
strOutput = string.Format("<span id=\"spanPhoneId-{0}\">{1}.{2}.{3} ( {4} ) <span id=\"divPopupMenu\" class=\"context-menu-{0}\"><a href=\"#\" title=\"Open Menu\" onclick=\"initializeContextMenuItemForLists({0})\">[ &Delta; ]</a></span><div id=\"divPopupMenuItems-{0}\" style=\"display: none;\"><ul class=\"bullet-arrow\"><li><a href=\"#divEditSpecifiedPhoneNumber\" class=\"inline UpdateLink phoneIdentity\" title=\"Edit Phone Number\">Edit the phone number</a></li><li><a href=\"#divRemoveSpecifiedPhoneNumber\" class=\"inline UpdateLink phoneIdentityDeletion\"data-phonenumber=\"{1}.{2}.{3} ( {4} )\" title=\"Remove Phone Number\">Remove this phone number</a></li></ul></div></span>", phoneNumber.PhoneId, phoneNumber.AreaCode, phoneNumber.PhoneNo.Substring(0, 3), phoneNumber.PhoneNo.Substring(3, 4), phoneNumber.PhoneNumberTypeInfo.PhoneNumberTypeName, PersonId, CompanyId);
```

the code for initialing the menu goes like :-

```
function initializeContextMenuItemForLists(intParameterId) {
var id = "#divPopupMenuItems-" + intParameterId;
jQuery.contextMenu({
    selector: '.context-menu-' + intParameterId,
    trigger: 'left',
    autoHide: true,
    items: jQuery.contextMenu.fromMenu(jQuery(id))
});
}
```

The problem is that when I edit a phone number and try to get the data attribute it is the old one only. The data attribute does not update in the context menu.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: no, nt yet. I think there is no solution for this out here.

Comment: can u replicate it in a fiddle or post more markup code..

Comment: fiddle is difficult because i am using the controller and helpers. If you tell me what you need to see i can explain that and post that content in it.

Comment: Can you show me the part where you are setting the data-attribute and retrieving it.

Comment: var phoneNumber = jQuery(this).data("phonenumber");
jQuery("#DeletePhoneId").val(phoneId);
this is the code i am using to set the phonenumber

Comment: And how are you getting it? You should be using  jQuery(this).data("phonenumber") provided `this` is the same element which hasn't changed.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help some users who would look at my question later on:-

I tried destroying the instance of the context menu I generated by following code:-

```
// Destroy the context menu selector already created for the particular instance
$.contextMenu("destroy", ".context-menu-one");
```

and that worked beautifully for me.

Hope this helps for others.